# How can I stop Unity from generating .meta files in my codesigned native plugin bundle?

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, dll, plugins

I've been working on a native unity plugin with the native code packaged as a macos bundle. I codesign it correctly, but when I add the plugin to the packages directory, Unity generates .meta files *inside* of the bundle, which of course invalidates the codesigning. Thus, Unity does not remove the `com.apple.quarantine` attribute which means I have to do it manually -- this doesn't really scale when other teams need to download and use this plugin.

I've also tried packaging the native code as a dylib (in the process changing the name from plugin.bundle to libplugin.dylib), but this hasn't worked. The dylib is never even detected.

I would really appreciate some help with this! My directory structure is as follows:

```
PluginDirectory
| Documentation
| Runtime
| | Interface
| | Plugins
| | | MacOS
| | | | plugin.bundle // items inside this have .meta files generated, invalidating the codesigning
| Editor
| Tests
```

I'm using Unity version 2020.3.25f1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you just add it manually or install it as it is supposed to be done?

- [Creating new local package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPackages.html#LocalMe)
- [Installing a package from a local folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui-local.html)

Comment: Yes, I installed it via the package manager.